# Как вывести ответ?

Tags: c++

Как вывести ответ в с++ в виде обыкновенной дроби?

Answer (score 2):

Небольшая иллюстрация к gmp (mpq/mpf не рекомендуется для новых проектов, рекомендуется mpfr, так что это неправильный пример)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gmpxx.h>
using namespace std;

int main (void) {
    double a;
    cin >> a;
    mpq_class a1 = a;
    cout << a1 << endl;
}

g++ -o mpq-example mpq-example.c++ -lgmpxx -lgmp

$ ./mpq-example
1.3365    
1504765225495167/1125899906842624
```

Странность результата вызвана тем, что рациональные числа хранятся в канонической форме, т.е. числитель и знаменатель не имеют общих множителей, а какова ошибка представления 1.3365 в double -- даже смотреть не хочется.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно, чтобы сократить два числа ?

```
int nsd(int a, int b) {
    while ( a!= b ) {
        if ( a > b ) a-=b; else b-=a;
    }

    return a;
}

void sokr_drob(int &x, int &y) {
    x /= nsd(x,y);
    y /= nsd(x,y);
}
```

Comment: Нет,сокращать нельзя...дана формула...она вычисляет значение...в итоге получается 1,3365... но для исследования этот результат не точен....необходимо представить его в виде обыкновенной дроби...видимо придется представлять исходную формулу в виде а/в... спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Ведите вычисления в рациональных числах (дробях). Библиотеки gmplib.org, www.mpfr.org и масса других. Будете иметь числитель и знаменатель. А уж как их напечатать -- дело ваше. Указанные библитеки -- сишные, но имеют биндинги (переходки) для c++. (gmp в своём составе имеет c++ интерфейс)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант запись через прямой слэш

```
printf("Fraction a/b = %d/%d", a, b);
```

где `a` и `b` - это целые (`int`) числа.